# Finding similarities (not duplicates) between elements of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a way to find the similarities (not the actual duplicates) within an array in PHP in order to get the "bigger picture". Essentially I'm scraping hashtags on specific Instagram posts, and then looking for correlations between them and a database of hashtag-relationships.

Currently I have an array that looks like:

```
array(15) {
  ["vietnam"]=>
  int(1617)
  ["vietnamtravel"]=>
  int(788)
  ["vietnamnow"]=>
  int(736)
  ["travelphotography"]=>
  int(583)
  ["visitvietnam"]=>
  int(540)
  ["hanoihandbook"]=>
  int(514)
  ["travel"]=>
  int(505)
  ["travelblogger"]=>
  int(491)
  ["vietnamtrip"]=>
  int(468)
  ["bestintravel"]=>
  int(462)
  ["sunsetporn"]=>
  int(460)
  ["instavietnam"]=>
  int(460)
  ["sky_sultans"]=>
  int(453)
  ["ig_sunsetshots"]=>
  int(423)
  ["traveller"]=>
  int(406)
}
```

Where the int() is an indication of the relevancy.

What I'm trying to achieve is extract the main keywords from this, to obtain an array containing "vietnam", "travel", "photography", "sunset" for example.

The brute-force way would be to compare each element of the array to the rest of the array and see how many occurrences can be found? This would work well for "vietnam" and "travel" since they're already in the array itself. However it wouldn't enable me to extract "sunset" or "photography" for example.

Any thoughts? :)

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: What result are you expecting? Draw it

Comment: I'm expecting an array containing "vietnam", "travel", "photography" and "sunset"

Comment: _“What I'm trying to achieve is extract the main keywords from this”_ - then either supply a full list of those, or explain _how_ you want to determine what the “main keyword” actually _is_.

Comment: That's the issue, I don't know what those main keywords are. I'm looking for correlations in that array that would point to what the main theme of the array is. In this array the words "travel" and "vietnam" pop up often, so it's safe to assume that they're the main theme of everything in the array.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help, You can `recursive` parse array starting from first array element

```
function _parseRecursive(&$array, &$carry){
  array_filter($array);
  $first = array_shift($array);
  $array = array_map(function($v) use ($first){
    return str_replace($first, '', $v);
  }, $array);
  $carry[] = $first;
  if(!$array) 
     return array_filter($carry);
  return _parseRecursive($array, $carry);
}
```

Use it like

```
 $result = _parseRecursive($a, $res);
```

Working example :https://3v4l.org/4tHSG

Answer (score 0):

If you need tags with this key words inside of (PHP function [stristr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)) then use next code:

```
echo "length of data array = ".count($data_ar)."\r\n";
$keys_like = ["vietnam","travel","sunset","photography"];

function new_arr ($keys, $data){
    $res = [];

    foreach($data as $key => $val){
        foreach($keys as $k){ 
                if(stristr($key, $k)){
                    $res[$key] = $data[$key];
                }  
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

$res_arr = new_arr($keys_like, $data_ar);
echo "length of resultant array = ".count($res_arr)."\r\n";
print_r($res_arr);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fbe11fc8f4aa7f01800816bdea10f03e277f68f)
Here you can choose what `keys` you need via `$keys_like`.

With help of @RakeshJakhar' function you can see the maximum number of appearances in `$data array`:

```
function _parseRecursive(&$array, &$carry){
    array_filter($array);
    $first = array_shift($array);
    $array = array_map(function($v) use ($first){
        return str_replace($first, '', $v);
    }, $array);
    $carry[] = $first;
    if(!$array) 
        return array_filter($carry);
    return _parseRecursive($array, $carry);
}  

function new_arr ($data, $rec_keys){
    $res = [];

    foreach($rec_keys as $item){
        $res[$item] = 0;
        foreach($data as $key => $val){ 
            if(stristr($key, $item)){
                $res[$item] += 1;
            }   
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$data_keys = [];
foreach($data_ar as $key=>$val){
    $data_keys[] = $key;
}

$rec_arr = _parseRecursive($data_keys, $res);

$res_arr = new_arr($data_ar, $rec_arr); 
arsort($res_arr);
print_r($res_arr);
```

[Demo2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c49876d2db509d7840ef1242aae74681e9ff0950)

Comment: The issue with this is that I need to input what I want as a result. The result should be $keys_like, not the input. I can't know in advance what the outcome is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

I Think It help you, If not please ignore it.

```
<?php
$whitelist = ["home","dashboard","profile","group"];
$possibleUserInputs = ["homd","hom","ashboard","settings","group"];
foreach($possibleUserInputs as  $input)
{
 if(preg_grep("/$input/i",$whitelist)
{
     echo $input." whitelisted";
}else{
     echo $input." flawed";
}

} 
?>
```

**Output**

homd flawed

hom whitelisted

ashboard whitelisted

settings flawed

group whitelisted

[See details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)